# implicit constructors for String class

Tags: c++, class-constructors

String s2("hi");

Do I have to write an implicit string constructor

String::String(const char* str);

or

would this constructor handle it:

String::String(const String &str);

Comment: So, when you tried this, what did you learn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create this string object, string (const char* s) constructor will be called, so there is a no need of writing a constructor.

Here are the constructors which are defined inside the std::string class

```
string();   
string (const string& str); 
string (const string& str, size_t pos, size_t len = npos);  
string (const char* s); 
string (const char* s, size_t n);   
string (size_t n, char c);  
template <class InputIterator>
  string  (InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
```

Further don't try to edit some standard libraries, It will lead to unwanted issues. if you want any customized functions, write a wrapper of your own.

Answer (score 0):

std::string already has a constructor to handle this. std::string s2("hill") will work without any problem.